# Locally closed dense subgroup of a topological group coincides with the whole group

Tags: topological-groups

This question is very simple, but I don't get the right idea.

> > Assume $H$ be a locally closed dense subgroup of a topological group $G$.
> >     Prove that $H=G$.

I need to prove that $gH\cap H\ne\emptyset$ for all $g\in G$.
I know that $H$ is open in $\overline{H}$, but I don't know of it is important.

Comment: Definitions are your friends.   What does it mean to be "locally closed'?

Comment: Means that (i) $H=U\cap F$ for some open $U$ and closed $F$; (ii) $H$ open in $\overline{H}$; (iii) for every $y\in H$ there is nhbd $N$ in $G$ s.t. $N\cap H$ is closed in $N$.

Comment: Wait! I apologize, but I want to prove that $H$ equals $G$. Now I edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you don't need the two assumptions on $H$, namely that $H$ is locally closed AND that it is open, because each one of these assumptions, separately, imply that $H$ is closed. Proofs of both these assertions can be found [here](https://wormtooth.com/20141023-locally-closed-subgroups/). Now since $H$ is also dense in $G$, its closure coincides with $G$, hence $H=G$.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I meant that $H$ is open in its closure... that was a typo